# It okay to use 12V 2.5A adapter instead of 12V 1A?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, amperage, adapter

I have a piano keyboard that uses 12V 1A adapter . The adapter was not working anymore so i used another one which was 12V 2.5A but after 45 minutes of usage the keyboard got little heated up in the area where the adapter is plugged in.Now my question is :1) have it caused some damage to the keyboard?? Although its working fine.
2) Is it okay to use that adapter?

Comment: Was there any other differences? Were both adapters DC or AC? Regulated or unregulated? Linear or switch mode? Did you measure the voltages?

Comment: What's a 'little heated up'? Too hot to touch? Warm? More than the old supply? It's not unusual for electronic devices to heat up when they are running. The degree matters...

Comment: I have a 12V, 1A DC power source. Its *measured* DC output voltage with no load  (0A) is **22V**. But just as its label says, it outputs 12V DC when delivering 1A instead of 0A. It is possible that your bigger 12V 2.5A power source is putting out more than 12V when loaded with your keyboard. A possible solution might add a resistor in-line. Some voltage measurements of no-load, and loaded power supply voltages would be useful to us.

Comment: Sounds like some fault in the keyboard killed the old adapter ... or possibly vice versa. The 2.5A one SHOULD work (assuming its regulated : otherwise it may supply more than 12V at only 1A) but the heating suggests some other damage.

Comment: Is the connector on the new adapter the same size? (both external and internal diameter). If it's a loose fit it could cause a poor connection and heat up the connector.

Answer (score 0):

The 2.5 A adapter is able to deliver more current than the older one.

That means that the 2.5 A adapter is more suitable than the older one.

You might have an electrical problem in the piano keyboard though.